# I have to run my code twice to get desired outcome, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm finding that I have to run my code twice for the desired output and I'm not sure why. It's also printing a long string of letters in the shell that aren't needed. I'd just like it to be a bit cleaner.
The code creates folders with subfolders, based on files names, then moves the files into specific subfolders.
Filename example is "A123456-20190101-A01.mp3"

```
import os  
import shutil

path = "/Volumes/ADATA UFD/For script/Files"
file_names = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if 
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file))]
file_map = {'O':'1-Original','P':'2-PreservationMaster','M':'3-Mezzanine','T':'4-Presentation','A':'5-Access','R':'6-Reference'}

parent_folders = set(file_name.rsplit('-', 1)[0] for file_name in file_names)
sub_folders = ['1-Original','2-PreservationMaster','3-Mezzanine','4-Presentation','5-Access','6-Reference']

for folder in parent_folders:
folder_path = os.path.join(path, folder)

try:
    os.mkdir(folder_path)
except:
    print('folder already exist:', folder_path)

for folders in sub_folders:
    try:
        folders_path = os.path.join(folder_path, folders)
        os.mkdir(folders_path)
    except:
        print('folder already exists:', folders_path)

for file_name in file_names:
    parent_folder = file_name.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
    ext = file_name[19]
    print(ext)
    dest = os.path.join(path, parent_folder, file_map[ext.upper()], file_name)
    src = os.path.join(path, file_name)
    try:
        shutil.move(src, dest)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I'm getting this error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/Volumes/ADATA UFD/For script/MoveFilesToPreservationBundleTest3.py", line 30, in <module>  
dest = os.path.join(path, parent_folder, file_map[ext.upper()], file_name)  
builtins.KeyError: '0'
```

Comment: Hard to say since we don't see your `file_names`. However, according to the traceback, you search the `file_map` dictionary for a key `t` when there is only a key with a capital `T`. You might want to change your keys or lookup the dictionary with capital letters only.

Comment: Are you sure you want `ext = file_name[19]` in this form? This is a single character from the filename (Likely why you're seeing "long string of letters in the shell that aren't needed")

Comment: What about: `dest = os.path.join(path, parent_folder, file_map[ext.upper()], file_name)`?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: @G.Anderson I'm not sure at all. I really struggled to get this single character out and couldn't find a different way to get it to work. Can you suggest a better way for me to do this please?

Comment: Thanks, @CristiFati. It's now returning a different KeyError - see edit.

Comment: Your key error shows a zero (0) and your file_map dictionary has a capital letter o (O).

Comment: @JustinEzequiel, I'm sorry, I'm not exactly sure what that means. Can you elaborate on what the problem is please? All singular characters in the file_map are capital letters. I'm not sure how that relates to the zero key error.

Comment: Your dictionary: `file_map = {'O':'1-Original',...}`; the error: `KeyError: '0'`; the code: `file_map[ext.upper()]`. All of which look like `ext='0'`, a zero instead of `'O'`, the letter.